# How do you recursively delete all hidden files in a directory on UNIX?

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I have been searching for a while, but can't seem to get a succinct solution. I have a Mac with a folder that I want to clean of all hidden files/directories - anything hidden. It used to be a Eclipse workspace with a lot of .metadata/.svn stuff, and I'm fine with all of it being removed. How can I do this (either with a shell script, Applescript, etc). Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`find . -name ".*" -print`

I don't know the MAC OS, but that is how you find them all in most *nix environments.

`find . -name ".*" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

to get rid of them...  **do the first find and make sure that list is what you want before you delete them all**.

The first `"."` means from your current directory.  Also note the second `".*"` can be changed to `".svn*"` or any other more specific name; the syntax above just finds all hidden files, but you can be more selective.  I use this all the time to remove all of the .svn directories in old code.

Comment: This will try to delete the current directory (which is named `.`).

Comment: 20:53:27:jmquigley@shire:samples(master): ~/tmp  
~>find . -name ".*" -exec rm -rf {} \;  
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'  
good point (but it doesn't remove it, but it does flag it).  I gave the ".svn*" option, which is a better option though.  (I hate the edits, LOL, can't format these I guess).

Comment: `find . -name ".*.*" -print` will find any file with at least one dot in the file name.

Comment: on a mac (10.4) the second command should ends with "\;" instead of "/;"

Comment: @jmq I think you meant to use a backslash rather than a foreslash: `\;`

Comment: [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) supports `+` instead of `\;` which should make the command more efficient.

Comment: @l0b0 bottleneck will be file operations anyway so it shouldn't matter that much

Comment: Also: if you want to skip the `.` and `..` folders, try to use `'.??*'` instead of `".*"` - it catches all hidden files with more than two letter names. (It still misses one letter names.)

Comment: Try first with `-ok` flag instead of `-exec` if worried about removal where it asks what to do.

Comment: As @DennisWilliamson mentions in his comment, this acts on the current directory which is bad if you're using a command like svn rm rather than rm -rf. Best to Dennis's suggested -mindepth 1 below.

Answer (score 19):

You need to be very careful and test any commands you use since you probably don't want to delete the current directory (`.`), the parent directory (`..`) or all files.

This should include only files and directories that begin with a dot and exclude `.` and `..`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name '.*' -delete
```

Answer (score 5):

```
rm -rf `find . -type f -regex '.*/\.+.+'`
```

If you want to delete directories, change `-type f` for `-type d`.

If you want to delete files and directories remove `-type f`.

UPDATE thanks to commenters: This fails for files or directories with spaces. Use [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061827/978704)

Comment: This fails for filenames that contain whitespace.

Comment: @Pauseduntilfurthernotice. I can't see why. On what system did it fail?

Comment: On any system that has `rm`, `find`, a shell like Bash or `sh` and file (or dir) names which include spaces. For a directory name "My Pictures" for example, your command will try to remove files from "My" and "Pictures" neither of which which may exist. You should use `find ... -exec ...` instead of a command substitution.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson absolutely. Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061827/978704) is far better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path -iname ".*" -type f -delete ;
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -rfileutils -e 'Dir["**/.*"].each{|x| FileUtils.rm(x) if File.file?(x)}'
```

Comment: that's easy to do by specifying `-type d` in the `find` command

Comment: `-iname` might be a little slower when you don't need it. If you include `-type d` and names starting with `.` it might try to delete the current directory which is named `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to delete empty directories. It starts at the bottom and works its way to the top. So, it won't doesn't fail if you reference the current path.

```
find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work quite well (in Bash on Linux at least):

```
find . -wholename '*/.*' -type f | sed -n '/\/\.[^\/]\+$/p' | xargs rm
```

You can tweak the regular expression in the `sed` call to your likings.

Be careful though: in my case, I have a lot of hidden files named `.gitignore` or `.gitkeep` that must be preserved. Be sure to check the list to see if anything is in there that you want to keep.

I've found this variant to be quite useful, it removes files like `._ANYTHING` (often trashed or tmp files):

```
find . -wholename '*/.*' -type f | sed -n '/\/\._[^\/]\+$/p' | xargs rm
```