# forrtl: No space left on device

Tags: linux, shell

My simulations stop with `forrtl: No space left on device` error.

When I use `ls --sort=size -alh`, it will report total of 96M and max of 60M usage. 
When I use `du -h`, it will report total of 159G and max of 158G (for the same folder) 
When I use `df -h`, it will report:

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

`/dev/nvme0n1p4                 930G  883G     0 100% /`

Initially, I thought that there are huge number of hidden files that are taking space. I tried to remove hidden files as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061638/how-do-you-recursively-delete-all-hidden-files-in-a-directory-on-unix).
However, I got the same result. I was wondering how I can find the space-consuming items to remove/delete them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ncdu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncdu) to find easier does directories that are using most of the space, for example, try this:

```
ncdu -x /
```

option `-x` is to stay in the same file system (do not traverse other filesystem mounts)

What also could be happening is that some applications/processes still running but haven't "free" the files, this is because the file descriptor in the filesystem is held open, in this case, you could use:

```
lsof  | grep deleted
```

Sometimes if a file is deleted while it is opened by a process, it will not actually free up the disk space until the process is ended.

More about this in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68532/53084

In case you can't use `ncdu` you could use the `find` command, for example, to find files bigger than 4096 bytes in the current directory:

```
find . -type f -size +4096c
```

More about other options here: https://superuser.com/a/204571/284722

Comment: I do not have it installed. Is there any way to do it without ncdu?

Comment: @Shabnam if possible try to install it, will save you lot of time

Comment: thanks for your complete explanations. I tried the "find ..." and understood which files are big and I am removing the unwanted ones now. I will try to install ncdu in future.